# how to classify a part of sentence using transformer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, transformers

The problem is like this: I have many sentences and for each sentence I have a continuous sequence of words that I want to mask out. Then I want to train a model to classify the masked part to 1/0.

The purpose is to train a model that can classify the masked part without using any information in the masked part but purely using the context information.

An example: “i borrow a book from Jason and it is interesting”. Without looking at Jason, the model should read “I borrow a book from MASK and it is interesting” and classify MASK as 1 (is a person name).

I know this looks like NER problem in the first place but because the limitations of the training data, treating it as NER problem leads to an overfitting solution. So I want the model to not looking at Jason itself but look at the context to make a binary classification decision.

My question is how can I turn this idea into a nlp problem and use Bert to model. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: “ because the limitations of the training data, treating it as NER problem leads to an overfitting solution”—what?

Comment: Let me explain myself clearer. The manual labeled training data only contain a small number of named entities and the real production contains many more unseen named entities. If I train an ner model, it only can recognize the tiny portion of the training data entities and miss many unseen ones. So I give up this idea. Instead, I need a model that doesn’t focus on the known entities themselves but focus on the context the named entities surrounding with. That way I may come up with a better generalized model

Comment: Just to give you some numbers, we have 10s of 1000s of documents and potential 100000s named entities but only 100 so ones were manually labeled for us.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is a data problem, not a modeling problem. You'll get far more 'bang for your buck' by annotating more data, compared to trying to find a way to fit a behemoth, data-hungry Transformer-based model to your limited data.

Comment: That is right. While data is improving by other teammates, I am researching possible modeling options as I can do my part of the work...